# Setting environment variable in ZSH gives number expected

Tags: zsh

I'm trying to set an array in ZSH (configured using oh-my-zsh).

```
export AR=(localhost:1919 localhost:1918)
```

but I'm getting an error like such:

```
zsh: number expected
```

If I don't add the export command, it's just fine.  I'm not typing the above in a *rc file, just in the zsh prompt.  What could be the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't `export` an array in zsh.

For more info: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html

> Note that you can't export arrays. If you export a parameter, then
> assign an array to it, nothing will appear in the environment; you can
> use the external command `printenv VARNAME` (again no `$` because the
> command needs to know the name, not the value) to check. There's a
> more subtle problem with arrays, too. The export builtin is just a
> special case of the builtin typeset, which defines a variable without
> marking it for export to the environment. You might think you could do
>
> `typeset array=(this doesn\'t work)`
>
> but you can't --- the special
> array syntax is only understood when the assignment does not follow a
> command, not in normal arguments like the case here, so you have to
> put the array assignment on the next line. This is a very easy mistake
> to make. More uses of typeset will be described in chapter 3; they
> include creating local parameters in functions, and defining special
> attributes (of which the `export` attribute is just one) for
> parameters.

Comment: Seems to be related to version of zsh. I had the same issue with zsh 5.0.x, but after upgrading to 5.3 the issue is gone.

Comment: Why is the error "number expected"?

Comment: @drevicko I'm guessing it's trying to cast it. But I'm not entirely sure