# 'git: : number expected' error coming when doing git branch

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I am in my local git repository and when I am doing: 'git branch', then the error coming up is:

> "git:960: number expected".

The number keeps increasing by 1 every time I run the git branch command.

Actually, the issue is coming with all git commands, like: `git status`, etc.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Which shell do you use? bash? zsh? which version of git ?

Comment: shell is zsh. But I cant find git version since, 'git --version' is not working. Actually, it was working till now, not why git has stopped working suddenly.

Comment: Could be an issue with zsh configuration. Something similar to https://github.com/nojhan/liquidprompt/issues/301. Try also with `bash` shell

Comment: Check your zsh environment. It could be that you wrongly defined some local array. See [Setting environment variable in ZSH gives number expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268083/setting-environment-variable-in-zsh-gives-number-expected) and [local array](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2013/msg00116.html)

Comment: run: which git - 
to show where it is located

Answer (score 2):

Close your terminal and start it again. It will work fine.