# How can I get shell array using process.env in node in zsh

Tags: node.js, shell, zsh

In zsh(v5.8), I can't read shell environment variable array using `process.env` in node.js(v12.20.1).

- ./env.js

```js
console.log(process.env);
```

---

```sh
# zsh
export TEST1=(xxx yyy)
export TEST2=zzz
node env.js

# results
{
    TEST2: 'zzz'
}
```

---

```sh
# bash
export TEST1=(xxx yyy)
export TEST2=zzz
node env.js

# results
{
    TEST1: '(xxx yyy)',
    TEST2: 'zzz',
}
```

So, How can I get shell array in node.js in zsh.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting environment variable in ZSH gives number expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268083/setting-environment-variable-in-zsh-gives-number-expected)

Comment: Umm. Thanks Comment @andlrc
The link says about that can't read array variable in zsh?
So, is it saying that node.js can't read shell array variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zsh supports array type for variable, but does not support array for environment.

- http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Guide/zshguide02.html

```sh
# example
# '-x' options, automatic export to the environment
typeset TEST1=(xxx yyy)
typeset -x TEST2=(aaa bbb) # ignore -x because, TEST2 type is arrays
typeset TEST3=xxx
typeset -x TEST4=aaa

echo $TEST1 $TEST2 $TEST3 $TEST4
# print all
xxx yyy aaa bbb xxx aaa

env
# print TEST4
{
    TEST4=aaa
}
```

---

Instead of directly handling the array type on zsh, it has been replaced by a way to solve it on node.
After reading in `string format` rather than array type, I solved it through `split()`.

- env.js

```js
console.log(process.env);
const CONST_TEST1 = process.env.TEST1.split(' ');
console.log(CONST_TEST1 instanceof Array);
console.log(CONST_TEST1);
```

```
# zsh
export TEST1='xxx yyy'
node env.js

# results
{
  TEST1: 'xxx yyy',
  _: '/Users/kmk/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node'
}
true
[ 'xxx', 'yyy' ]
```